# Difference between $\mathbb{E}[Y|X]$ and $\mathbb{E}[Y|X=x]$

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, density-function, conditional-expectation

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{A}, \mathbb{P})$ be a probability space and $X: \Omega \rightarrow \mathcal{X}$ and $Y: \Omega \rightarrow \mathcal{Y}$ be random variables.

I have two questions comparing the conditional expectations $\mathbb{E}[Y|X]$ and $\mathbb{E}[Y|X=x]$.

1.) What is the difference between $\mathbb{E}[Y|X=x]$ and $\mathbb{E}[Y|X]$ in terms of their mathematical properties? I.e., from which space to which space do they map, which variables are they functions of and if they are measurable?

2.) If $X$ and $Y$ are absolutely continuous real valued random variables and have a joint density $f_{X, Y}$ with respect to the Lebesgue-measure $\lambda \otimes \lambda =\lambda^2$,  Then:
$$\mathbb{E}[Y|X=x] = \int y \, f_{Y|X=x}(y) \, \lambda(dy) = \int  y \, \frac{f_{X, Y}(x,y)}{f_X(x)}\lambda(dy).$$

My question is now, how would that equation look like for $\mathbb{E}[Y|X]$? Does it make sense to write something like $f_{Y|X=X}(y)$ and $f_{X,Y}(X,y)$ and do these quantity even exist? I.e., should I write
$$\mathbb{E}[Y|X] = \int y \, f_{Y|X=X} \lambda(dy) = \int  y \, \frac{f_{X, Y}(X,y)}{f_X(X)}\lambda(dy)$$?

Comment: $\mathbb{E}[Y\mid X=x]$ is a value which depends on $x$, while $\mathbb{E}[Y\mid X]$ is a function of $X$ and so a random variable.  If you define $g(x) = \mathbb{E}[Y\mid X=x]$, then you can say $\mathbb{E}[Y\mid X]= g(X)$

Comment: So but then $\mathbb{E}[Y|X=x]$ is also a function of $x$, no?

Comment: $g(x)$ is a function of $x$, though for given $x$ it is just a value. But it is not a random variable or a function of a random variable

Comment: So what I am wondering is how I should interprete $\mathbb{E}[Y|X=x]$. So is that a function $g(\cdot)$ or is it a function value with a specific fixed $x$, i.e., is it the function $g$ evaluated at $x$, $g(x)$?

Comment: It is certainly the later, since it is the conditional expectation of $Y$ given that $X$ takes the specific value $x$.

Comment: ok thx. And could you tell me if it is correct how I have written $\mathbb{E}[Y|X}$ in terms of the densities? I.e., that I put the random variable $X$ as the argument, where normally a realization $x$ would be?

Comment: can somehone help?