# General and specific ways to compute the conditional expectation

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{A}, \mathbb{P})$ be a probability space and $X: \Omega \rightarrow \mathcal{X}$ and $Y: \Omega \rightarrow \mathcal{Y}$ be random variables.
If $X$ and $Y$ are absolutely continuous real valued random variables and have a joint density $f_{X, Y}$ with respect to the (product) Lebesgue-measure $\lambda \otimes \lambda =\lambda^2$, that is, $\mathbb{P}_{X, Y}(B, C)=\int_{B \times C}f_{X, Y}(x, y)\lambda^2(dx, dy)=\int_B \int_C f_{X, Y}(x, y)\lambda(dx) \lambda(dy) $ with Borel sets $B$ and $C$. Then:

$$\mathbb{E}[Y|X=x] = \int y \, f_{Y|X=x}(y) \, \lambda(dy) = \int  y \, \frac{f_{X, Y}(x,y)}{f_X(x)}\lambda(dy).$$

Under which conditions can this formulation of the conditional expectation be used? And if these conditions do not hold, how can the conditional expectation then be calculated?

Comment: Wasn't this answered in the thread you started at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/531705/regular-conditional-distribution-vs-conditional-distribution?

Comment: also related to https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/549684/difference-between-mathbbeyx-and-mathbbeyx-x

Comment: @ Henry, yes previously these two questions were posted as one, but I was asked by the mods to split them up into two

Comment: @whuber unfortunately I still dont know what the conditions are when I can use the formulation in terms of the densities and when I have to use a more general version (and how I would do it in the more general case)

Comment: Ariel's answer at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/531806/919 copiously addresses that issue.